# Windows Authentication for Life Ray 6.2

Tags: windows, authentication, liferay, single-sign-on

I need to do windows authentication(Intranet users) for LifeRay Login Portal. LifeRay Login uses same UID and PWD which is used for Windows Login. Both Windows Login and LifeRay login interacts with Active Directory for Authentication. So My requirement is to land user on HomePage instead of asking user credentials.

After Doing R&D I came to conclusion that I should use option provided in LifeRay Admin Portal(Authentication) - CAS SSO  / NTLM SSO .

I am not clear which option will be correct for my requirement OR any other option you see fitting as solution for my requirement.

Kindly Help.

Comment: As per my understanding,CAS is generally used where in a central authentication mechanism is needed for multiple applications whereas NTLM (NT LAN Manager) is windows protocol suite and would be best suited to ur current business need.

Comment: Thansk for the suggestion Shivam. I am going with that approach only. Have implemented Windows SSO for LifeRay?

Comment: Not myself,but you can explore the Liferay documentation for the same.